# what is the type of a query in Realm Swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I have the result of a query in Realm and now I'd like to use 'results' as a global variable.

```
let results = self.realm.objects(Table)
```

What actually is the type of 'results' in above example? In the documentation it says that Queries return a Result instance, but what does that mean in regards to the type? I tried to define 'results' as

```
var results = [Table]()
```

but that does not work.

Comment: It is open source so you can just find it in source code. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/a347867d0c886648ec8f240cf2ef26b7d686aff3/RealmSwift/Realm.swift#L1042

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can option-click on `results` to view the inferred type.

In this case, if you look at the documentation for [`objects(_:)`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift5Realm7objectsuRxCS_6ObjectrFMxGCS_7Resultsx_), you'll see that it returns a `Results<T>`, where `T` is the type speicifed by the parameter (`Table`, in this case).

Comment: great thanks, the option-click thing is great, I wish I'd known that earlier. Anyway, I tried to define the global var as per your instruction and it worked (var results:Results<Table>!).

Comment: @kangarooChris That implicitly unwrapped optional worries me